# Can node modules folder which is downloaded with nodejs installation locally, be set up as jfrog local repo

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, artifactory

Is it possible to create a private repository hosting packages which are downloaded with node.js installation?  After downloading nodejs locally can I zip the default node modules folder which is available and make it a local npm repo in jfrog so that when i give npm install command, the pacakged should be downloaded from this repo. I want to have the packages of node modules folder of nodejs version (14.4.0) as a repository in jfrog instead of having a remote npm repo which pulls packages from [www.npmjs.org](http://www.npmjs.org). Reason for not wanting remote npm repo is

1: It pulls different new version which is available in npmjs.org

2: Third party API call from jfrog is something that my organization doesn't permit for a project.

Comment: You can achieve this goal, but your path is wrong. A package that was installed on system A doesn't have to work on system B, e.g. you can't install sqlite3 on a x86 architecture and use it on an ARMv6 architecture.

Comment: @jabaa Thank you for responding, you are right about this. Can i zip the node modules folder of my project code ( which is currently created locally when we give npm install) and push that as a repo to jfrog local repository

Comment: I don't know if you can push it to a a jfrog local repository, but I know that you possibly can't use it on other systems. There are packages that need different installation steps depending on the operating system. There are packages that don't exist for some operating systems. Some packages are compiled for exactly one architecture. You can't copy a `node_modules` folder to an arbitrary other system and expect it to work.

Comment: @jabaa Understood. Given my situation, what might be the best solution to have a local private repository of a particular version of npm (6.14.5) without facing any compliance issue in the company or it making a third party api call to official npm website once it is set up.

Comment: Store the packages in the repository.